# vs2015 update 1 compile typescripts to multiple js

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have a project with multiple typescripts and I was looking for a way to compile groups of these files into separate JS files. IE:

- Scripts\Group1\file1.ts
- Scripts\Group1\file2.ts
- Scripts\Group2\file3.ts
- Scripts\Group2\file4.ts

Compiled JS (on save)

- Scripts\group1.js
- Scripts\group2.js

I did look into having multiple tsconfig.json files but for the life of me I couldn't get the project to even look at 1 tsconfig.json file. It seems like they are also having problems with tsconfig.json and VS2015

Is it even possible to compile to multiple JS files with Visual Studios TypeScript compiler?

I'm running: VS2015 update 1, TypeScript 1.7.6.0 (came with vs update 1), .net 4.6 web application

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you to install npm and gulp and build typescript there. You can do what you need in a very easy and easy-to-configure way. I migrated to that solution half a year ago and I cannot express how happy I am. In fact, VS2015 has a nice support for that  called the Task Runner Window for running gulp tasks.

Comment: I'll look into that. Do you know if I can run that on save/build locally? Also, would you know how easy it is to integrate this with TFS builds? Integrating with TFS builds is very important. Thanks

Comment: I have just integrated that in my VSO build. It was simple. The task runner provides options to hook the gulp build task to Pre-Build, Post-Build, Project-Start and one more I believe. There is one problem with the VSO build - there is a bug with npm, but that is getting solved quickly and there are several workarounds.

Comment: I did go with npm and gulp for my TFS build. Just curious, for your VSO build, when running "npm install" did you get "npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0" error as well? This causes my build to partial succeed. How did you handle this? I know its a warning, but have a partial build isn't good.

Comment: Using "npm --loglevel=error install" ignores the error on TFS build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it work using npm and gulp. For anyone trying to do something similar:

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {    
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "2.10.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0"    
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js (part of it to generate 1 file)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
gulp.task('compileTypeScriptFiles', function () {
  var tsResult = gulp.src(['Scripts/file1.ts', 'Scripts/file2.ts'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // This means sourcemaps will be generated 
    .pipe(typescript({
      noImplicitAny: false,
      target: 'ES5',
      removeComments: true,
      out: 'final.js',
      preserveConstEnums: true,
      noEmitOnError: false
  }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // write sourcemap to same folder
  .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts'));
});
```

For local development (VS 2015) bind the action to Task Runner Explorer after build.

For TFS build server, you will need to:

- Install node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.12.0/)
- install rimraf. This is required to remove the node_module folder in your build since windows has problems deleting this folder. Open up the node cmd and run "npm install rimraf -g"
- create a powershell an attach to the pre-build event.

My powershell

```
Param (
  [string]$path = $env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
)

cd $path

# install npm from package.json. There is a know error thrown here (actual npm warning) for outdated scripts. This error will be ignored
&npm --loglevel=error install 

# compile typescript from gulpfile.js
&node_modules\.bin\gulp compileTypeScriptFiles

# remove node modules.
&rimraf $path\node_modules
```

Hope this helps